# What is the appropriate way to add a click event in place of a hover event added to pictures in an org chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been tasked to take some pre-existing code which has a `float` event on an org chart. When you hover over an individual on the org chart a picture pops up and displays all the employees under them.

They don't like that and would like it changed to a click event. I've listed the code for the float event but what would be an example of taking the *contentFloating* and making it a click event? Looking for the proper syntax please.

```css
}
.orgContainer .contentStable .contentFloating img {
  height: 720px;
  width: 960px;
}

/* Float content */
.orgContainer .contentFloating {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
.orgContainer .contentStable:hover .contentFloating {
  display: block;
  top: 7%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentStable">
  <img title="Scott Plemmons Director Supplier Quality Compliance" src="/sites/scm/utas_supp_qual/Home_Pictures/scott_plemmons.jpg" />
  <p>
    Scott Plemmons<br/> Director
    <br/> Supplier Quality
  </p>
  <div class="contentFloating">
    <img src="/sites/scm/utas_supp_qual/Home_Pictures/Org_Charts/Scott_Plemmons_Chart.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're confusing css with js. There are no events in css, unless you're talking about pseudo elements like :active

Comment: `.contentStable:hover` is the only CSS in your code that responds to hovering the mouse over an element. Remove the `:hover` to disable that. Then you will have to create a click event handler in javascript that adds and removes the class that shows the picture.

Comment: Can you elaborate the terms "_float event_" and "_quick event_", never heard of them before.

Comment: I'm more than likely using improper terms, I apologize for that as I guess it's confusing you guys.

Comment: @Kokodoko could you provide an example of a click even handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to add a click event handler to a dom element, and then make another div appear when you click on it.

**html**

```
<div class="orgchart">click for details</div>
<div id="details">details</div>
```

**css**

```
#details {
  position:absolute;
}
```

**javascript**

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("orgchart");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
     elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        // get the position of the element that was clicked
        let clickedItem = e.target;
        var rect = clickedItem.getBoundingClientRect();
        // set the details div to that position and fill it with content
            let details = document.getElementById("details");
        details.innerHTML = "Joe Average";
        details.style.left = (rect.left + 10) + "px";
        details.style.top = (rect.top + 20) + "px";
        });
}
```

Check a [jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/vsvu6o5v/26/)